# Cake 2 Shell: Undefined method success()

Tags: php, cakephp

I wrote a Cake-Shell that uses Cake-Shell method "success()" but this is declared as undefined. I cant find any thread in the web describing that problem. I can tell that the shell did run fine severeal weeks ago.

Method-Call:

```
$this->success('success', array());
```

I call the shell in my Windows-CLI via

```
cake ImportItems
```

and its obviously running through it but throws an error when should fire $this->success():

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ImportItemsShell::success() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myCake\app\Console\Command\ImportItemsShell.php on line 29

Here's my Code of the Shell

```
require_once('libraries/Ini.php');
class ImportItemsShell extends AppShell {

/**
 * Main fn
 */
public function main() {
    $this->importItems();
}

/**
 * Get called by Cron
 */
protected function importItems() {
    $Shop= new Shop(SHOP_DB); 
    $items = Api::getItems(true);
    $mysql = MySQL::getInstance();
    $res = array();

    if(is_array($items) && ($items['status'] == Api::STATUS_OK)) {
        $Shop->importItems($items['values']);
        $this->success('success', $items['values']);
    } else {
        $this->error('invalid_item_response', array());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct, there is no `Shell::success()` method in Cake 2.x. In contrast to errors, which can be written to `stderr` using `Shell::error()` or `Shell::err()`, a "success" message would simply be written to `stdout` using `Shell::out()`.

Maybe it's just your error reporting settings that have changed?

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html for more information.